# In spin systems, a mean field with nonzero Chern number after Gutzwiller projection changed into trivial state?

Tags: condensed-matter, spin-models

The mean field is nontrivial because of nonzero Chern number. The gauge symmetry is Z2. Under Gutzwiller projection, I calculate the ground state degeneracy(GSD) and find that the GSD is one(trivial phase).Is the situation possible? How to understand?